# get count of highest 4 values in a table and save as variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system for question answering. when a user answers a question the value selected in inserted into a database with structure
answer_id,question_id,option_letter

now i want to count the option_letter and find the highest 4 values that were chosen as answer then save this highest values in 4 different variables for use later on.

this is my sql statement am trying to use a foreach but am getting invalid statement passed. and i dont think that the way am doing it will give me for distinct variables for the four highest values

```
$var1='';
$que= $this->query("SELECT COUNT(options), option_letter FROM personality_answer GROUP BY option_letter ORDER BY COUNT(options) DESC");
    foreach($que as $row):
       $var1= $row['option_letter'];
    endforeach;

    echo $var1;
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$que` is a valid array? We don't know what your `query` function returns. Can you provide that code, and also `print_r` the result of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your data structure correctly, this will get you the 4 most frequent option_letters:

```
SELECT COUNT(answer_id), option_letter 
FROM personality_answer 
GROUP BY option_letter 
ORDER BY COUNT(answer_id) DESC
LIMIT 4;
```

I would put them into an array:

```
$letters = [];
foreach ($que as $row) {
    $letters[] = $row['option_letter'];
}
```